# Import JavaScript file in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Include a JavaScript file in a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991492)
>   [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087)

What is the best way to import a JavaScript file, for example `file.js`, in a JavaScript function()?

For example, what is the best way to replace the todo statement:

```
function doSomething() {
   if (xy.doSomething == undefined) {
      // TODO: load 'oldVersionPatch.js'
   }
   ...
}
```

Possibly the best solution is to create script element and add it into the HTML page.

- Is it better to add/append it into head, or body (what will load when)?
- Is it better to use JavaScript or [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) (what is more cross-browser compatible)?

Comment: yes, but there have been many answers. I am not sure if it is better to add the script to head, body (what will load when), to use jquery or standard javascript (what is more cross browser compatible)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

or

```
(function(){
  this.__defineGetter__("__FILE__", function() {
    return (new Error).stack.split("\n")[2].split("@")[1].split(":").slice(0,-1).join(":");
  });
})();

(function(){
  this.__defineGetter__("__DIR__", function() {
    return __FILE__.substring(0, __FILE__.lastIndexOf('/'));
  });
})();

function include(file,charset) {
    if (document.createElement && document.getElementsByTagName) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.setAttribute('src', __DIR__ + '/' + file);
        if(charset){
            script.setAttribute('charset', charset);
        }
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I used the jquery style: $.getScript('xyz.js', function() {}); Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
  var filename = 'oldVersionPatch.js';
  var js = document.createElement('script');
  js.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  js.setAttribute("src", filename);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
```

.. should do it

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) create a `<script>` element, append the `src` attribute with whatever the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is and attach to the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your code asynchronous to gain this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = yourJavascriptFileLocation;
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (!script.readyState || script.readyState === 'complete') {
        /* Your code rely on this JavaScript code */
    }
};
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
// Don't use appendChild
head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

Comment: why shouldn't I use appendChild?

Comment: if there is as `<base>` element in `<head>` section that is the last child of `<head>`, `appendChild` in IE6 would result in buggy behavior, that is, the whole DOM is appended to the `<base>` element :)